# Is there any way to run both PHP and ASP in the same server running IIS?

Tags: php, iis

Very direct question, i need to know if its possible and maybe where to start reading about that. Im a programmer with zero experience in windows servers and a client is asking if we can deliver in their windows boxes(and no they wont let us use any kind of virtualization in them).

Thanks guys, i know its not 100% programming related but... hope you can help =)

EDIT: Wow, fast reply! Thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy. Just run the ISAPI installer from the PHP websiite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I don't think there is anything different about the setup.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly this setup - ISAPI PHP on a production server running windows 2003/IIS for the last couple of years.  The majority of code on the site is PHP there's a little ASP too.  Never had a single issue with it.

PHP on Windows is extremely stable.  Personally I like it because I can then easily use my favourite database - SQLServer - the so-called WISP stack.

Disclaimer is that this isn't a particularly heavily used server - as can be seen from having SQLServer on the same box - but it fronts a publicly available service sector website and the a significant web application for the same organisation so does see significant real-world use.